# Replacing special character by new line

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

I have following lines in a text file. I would like to remove last '_' and add a new line character after that.

```
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G_CCAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTG
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G_CAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGA
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G_AATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGAT

Desired output:

>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
CCAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTG
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
CAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGA
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
AATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGAT
```

I have used below SED query to perform this operation. I am not able to figure out the problem in my query.

```
sed 's/\_/'\n'/g'
```

Comment: Single quotes can't be nested.

Comment: If your `sed` has problems with the newline in the `\n` replacement part, just type a literal line break there, or use a variable (but then use double quotes around the `sed` command). Matching last `_` can also be done with `_([^_]*)$` POSIX ERE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `.*` eat as much of the line as it can (because `*` is greedy) before matching `_`,

```
sed 's/\(.*\)_/\1\n/' file
```

or the debatably nicer

```
sed -E 's/(.*)_/\1\n/' file
```

Concerning your attempt, it has 3 errors:

- `_` needs not be escaped
- `'` cannot be nested (this is because of the shell, not of `sed`); fwiw, I don't understand why you've put them there: what were you trying to do?
- if you fix the two above, ending up with `sed 's/_/\n/g'`, you would be substituting all `_`s, rather than only the last one.

Comment: Oh, @rshar, that's a good reason to accept my answer, isn't it? Besides, the first and second command do the same thing. The latter gets rid of some backslashes thanks to the `-E` option, which uses extended regular expressions.